# Hiding a GridView row if something is older than 31 days

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to make a row hide in my `GridView` depending on if a date is older than 31 days. I can currently work out which fit the criteria I'm just having difficulty removing it from my `GridView` after I have found what needs removing.

This code is currently located in the page load function:

```cs
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    String Test = row.Cells[2].Text;
    Debug.WriteLine(Test);
    DateTime Date2 = Convert.ToDateTime(Test);
    Double Result = (Date2 - DateTime.Now).TotalDays;

    Debug.WriteLine(Result);

    if (Result < -32)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh");
        row.Visible = false;

    }  
}
```

I'm looking to hide any row that returns a value over -31. There is currently no output, but all the debugs show currently.

Comment: Why not change the DB query instead?

Answer (score 0):

> Displaying data in a tabular format is a task you are likely to
>   perform frequently. The DataGridView control is designed to be a
>   complete solution for displaying tabular data with Windows Forms . The
>   DataGridView control is highly configurable and extensible, and it
>   provides many properties, methods, and events to customize its
>   appearance and behavior.

The following C# source code manually creates a DataGridView columns and rows and hide the second column and second row.

```
dataGridView1.Rows[Index].Visible = false;

dataGridView1.Columns[Index].Visible = false;
```

**EXAMPLE****:**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Product ID";
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Product Name";
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Product Price";

            string[] row = new string[] { "1", "Product 1", "1000" };
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
            row = new string[] { "2", "Product 2", "2000" };
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
            row = new string[] { "3", "Product 3", "3000" };
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
            row = new string[] { "4", "Product 4", "4000" };
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);

            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Visible = false;
            dataGridView1.Rows[1].Visible = false;

        }
    }
}
```